# Show that the the set of magic squares of order n is a vector subspace of $M_{n,n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> A squared matrix is called a magic square if the sum of the elements along any
>   row, column and both diagonals is a constant.

It is clear to show the zero vector is a magic square.

However, how can I show two general magic squares gives another magic square? And to show it is closed under scalar multiplication?

Comment: Write down two magic squares. Add them - is the result a magic square? What if you double the entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule for an $n$ by $n$ matrix to be a magic square is that $2n + 2$ equations have to give the same value.  (Add any row, any column, or either diagonal.)  Or equivalently, any of those minus the first is 0.  So that turns it into $2n-1$ linear equations give 0.  (One of the equations is the first minus itself, which is trivially true.)

Now you have to prove that if you have 2 magic squares, any linear combination of them satisfies the $2n-1$ linear equations that make it a magic square as well.